# Can an equilibrium point of an autonomous differential equation be one that makes the function undefined?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

In my book I was asked to find the equilibrium points of the function.

dy/dt = ryln(K/y)

where r and K are both constants.

I found that y = K, and I thought about y = 0, but chose not to include it because it would make the function undefined. However the book states that the two points are y= K and y = 0. How can that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be because the right-hand side is not undefined when approached from above.  Expanding the equation using the properties of logarithms, we get

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} = r\,y\left[\ln(K) - \ln(y)\right] = r\,y\,\ln(K) - r\,y\ln(y)
$$

The middle expression again shows your first $y=K$ answer (this time via subtraction instead of division).  The last expression raises the possibly that $y=0$ may be an equilibrium point if $y\ln(y)$ is defined in the limit as $t\rightarrow0^+$.  Noticing that $0\ln(0)$ is an indeterminate form of $0\times\infty$, let's use L'Hospital's Rule placing the reciprocal of $y$ on the bottom:

$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow0^+} \frac{\ln(y)}{\frac{1}{y}} = 
\lim_{t\rightarrow0^+} \frac{\frac{1}{y}}{-\frac{1}{y^2}}=
\lim_{t\rightarrow0^+} -y = 0
$$

Therefore, the function has a defined limit at $y=0$: $0$.